# In DocuSign template create hyperlink with mailto protocol

Tags: docusignapi

In DocuSign template I want to setup a hyperlink with **mailto** protocol, TO, CC, Subject etc. Something like below which will open default mail client compose window with given info pre-populated.

```
mailto:intake@gmail.com?CC=copy-to@gmail.com&Subject=email-subject-goes-here&Body=Please-attach-your-your-files
```

I know how to create simple hyperlink with http protocol using Custom Text Field in template. But same approach does not work with mailto protocol.

Same question has been asked on DocuSign support page here https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k8jZ/adding-email-hyperlink-in-a-template but no concluding answer.

Can someone help, if its possible to have link with mailto promotocol on docusign template or not?

Comment: If a question below helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe the functionality currently exists to enable the mailto scheme in custom text fields.

However, there is a workaround...if you are **particularly** motivated by this requirement, you can leverage the [Responsive Signing](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/creating-signable-html) feature and only provide a document rendered in html to DocuSign.

Ex: 
POST /envelopes

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "theDoc",
            "htmlDefinition": {
                "source": "<a href=\"mailto:test@test.com\"> Click me! </a>"
            }
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
    ...
```

All of your  tags containing mailto schemes will be honored.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, like other answer above also suggested, I think responsive signing will be helpful in this case. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you need to use HTML instead of PDF for your document. That doesn't only mean you upload HTML, but you actually have to tell DocuSign to handle it as HTML the whole way.
this is called "Responsive Signing" since the experience for the end-user is different (better).

[This article](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/creating-signable-html) explains in detail how to go about doing this. Note that for security reasons, there are all sorts of limitations about the HTML that is used. I'm not aware about a specific mailto: limitation, it should work.

I'm not sure your use-case, but a completely different approach might be to have the email sent from SMTP server and by your integration.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will try the responsive signing.